# Remove Embedded Vimeo Video Border with Javascript

Tags: javascript, vimeo, revolution-slider

I've been trying to remove a border that is around an embedded Vimeo video on my site. I've tried removing the border with CSS and JS to no avail.

I'm wondering if there is a way to remove the border using Javascript.

The video can be seen here at the top of the page: http://feliciasantos.com/handforgedworks/

Answer (score 0):

Felicia, I think the video content itself is uploaded to Vimeo with top and bottom black borders which makes it almost impossible to remove them with JS or CSS.

See the standalone player here: https://player.vimeo.com/video/292992048

(It can be done since it's a background video and the controls are not needed but it's not so easy, you'll have to find out the correct aspect ratio of only the video content without the black borders. So take the height of the video content and divide it by the width. That's the ratio. Next you'll have to wrap the iframe in a div which confirms to that ratio with a `overflow: hidden` where the iframe is positioned absolutely in the center of the div, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/luwes/grybtsfm/)

However the best way to make it work is to crop the original video to remove the black borders and re-upload that to Vimeo.

Hope this helps.